# How to trigger manually and event using ElapsedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net

How to trigger manually a method that is being used as an event ElapsedEventArgs

```
// this run every X minutes

int periodMilliSeconds = periodMinutes * 60000;
timerStatus = new System.Timers.Timer(periodMilliSeconds);
timerStatus.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerStatus);



// But I need to run this method at user interaction even Elapsed has not being fired
// Method to call pro grammatically not from the Timer

private static void OnTimerStatus(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the method with empty parameters, if you do not need them.

```
// Somewhere else
OnTimerStatus(null, null);
```